# POSTing metrics to prometheus pushgateway in groovy fails with 400

Tags: java, curl, groovy, prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I'm trying to translate a working curl command to groovy, so I can natively execute it in my Jenkins pipeline. My problem is that the curl command works, but my groovy request fails with a 400 error from the pushgateway of prometheus. My code in groovy looks like this:

```
def post = new URL("https://prometheus_url").openConnection();
def message = '''
# TYPE some_metric counter
some_metric{label="val1"} 42
# TYPE another_metric gauge
# HELP another_metric Just an example.
another_metric 2398.283
''';

post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
post.with {
  doOutput = true
  requestMethod = 'POST'
  outputStream.withWriter { writer ->
    writer << message.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
  }
  println content.text
}
assert post.responseCode == 200
```

The error that I'm receiving is

```
Caught: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://prometheus_url
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://prometheus_url
```

The working curl command that I'm trying to copy is the following

```
cat <<EOF | curl --data-binary @- 'https://prometheus_url' -vvv
# TYPE some_metric counter
some_metric{label="val1"} 42
# TYPE another_metric gauge
# HELP another_metric Just an example.
another_metric 2398.283
EOF
```

So my question is, what am I missing between my groovy code and the curl command to be receiving this error?

**EDIT**: I'm adding the verbose text from the working curl operation

```
cat <<EOF | curl --data-binary @- 'https://prometheus_url' -vvv
# TYPE some_metric counter
some_metric{label="val1"} 42
# TYPE another_metric gauge
# HELP another_metric Just an example.
another_metric 2398.283
EOF
*   Trying X.X.X.X...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to prometheus_url (X.X.X.X) port XYZ (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / --------------------
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=--------------------
*  start date: Jun 17 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 16 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "prometheus_url" matched cert's "----------------"
*  issuer: C=--; O=--------; OU=-------- CA 1B; CN=--------
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST ------------------------ HTTP/1.1
> Host: prometheus_url
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
> Accept: */*
> Referer:
> Content-Length: 147
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 147 out of 147 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 06 Aug 2021 13:18:39 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host prometheus_url left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't content-type be `application/octet-stream`?

Comment: hey @tim_yates, is it? I tried this too, it didn't seem to do anything differently. Thanks thought.

Comment: I don't believe `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is right... The curl example doesn't do that, does it? Why are you encoding to base64? Not sure the curl example is doing that either?

Comment: Possibly, an issue too. My understanding was that this is how prometheus is expecting it?

Comment: Went and read the docs for curl ;-) https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary So AFAIK, your content type is fine, but you don't need to encode the bytes, just send them down the OutputStream with `outputStream << message.bytes`

Comment: @EvanP, you curl command with -vvv should log the whole request/response please share it then we could help.

Comment: @daggett you are right, I should had mentioned that too. The curl command inserts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` that's why I had it like that in the first place. The reason that I's open for another opinion was in the case that groovy was encoding the message differently and needed a different content-type header. FYI I've edit and added the actual verbose.

Comment: why you are doing base64 encoding in groovy when  you don't have this in curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling further with the code, it seems that the base64 encoding wasn't needed after all. Thus a more simplified and working code is the following:

```
def post = new URL("https://prometheus_url").openConnection();
def message = """
# TYPE some_metric counter
some_metric{label="val1"} 42
# TYPE another_metric gauge
# HELP another_metric Just an example.
another_metric 2398.283
""";

post.setRequestMethod("POST");
post.setDoOutput(true);
post.getOutputStream().write(message.bytes);

assert post.responseCode == 200
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the http status code 400 as well until I added a line break at the end of the metric.

After that my call worked. I don't know exactly how the message constructed by your "triple quote" looks like at the end of the day, but I suspect you had the same problem as I did.